# Calculate time difference button

Tags: php

Hi I am new to javascript and php. I have a form that has three text boxes, starttime, endtime and results. I am trying to take the starttime and endtime and find how much time has passed and display this in the results. How can I go about this?

here is my html:

```
    <form action="JobChangeTimeSheet.php" method="GET">
  Machine Stopped at:
 <input type="time" name="start_date"/>


End of TO:
<input type="time" name="since_start"/>  
<input type="submit"> 

Total time

<?PHP
if (! empty($_GET['start_date'])){

$start_date = new DateTime($_GET['start_date']);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($_GET['since_start']));
echo $since_start->days.' days ';
echo $since_start->h.' hours';
echo $since_start->i.' minutes';

}
?>
</form>
```

You can see there are 2 text boxes, a button, and a third disabled text box. I am trying to view the difference in minutes between the two text boxes in the third text box

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include more details including your code that isn't currently working. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok now i have tried fixing the structure

Comment: I edited my original post with what I have working so far. On submit, the php calculates the time that passed correctly, now I just need a button or a way to calculate before submitting the page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a code I can work on, I will guide you exactly through the steps on how to do this.

Load your HTML input in PHP vars named `$start_date` and `$end_date`. Use these lines:

```
$start_date = new date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($start_date));
$end_date = new date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($end_date));
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
$hours   = $interval->format('%h'); 
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
echo  'Difference in minutes is: '.($hours * 60 + $minutes);
```

***PS:*** You are talking about Javascript in your question but no Javascript code has been presented in your code. Are you using some sort of DateTimePicker?

Comment: Sorry no i did not include it I have scrapped my previous attempts. I have been attempting all day with no luck.The main issue is I want to be able to display the difference on a button click so it can be displayed in the form, but not refresh the page.